# Как подключить libpq-dev на windows

Tags: c++, postgresql

Как подключить libpq-dev на windows??? очень срочно нужна помощь

Comment: Первые строчки в гугле вам ответят на все windows libpq

Answer (score 0):

Советую MSYS2. WSL и Cygwin обычно используют, чтобы запускать на винде непортабельные приложения, которые иначе под ней не работают.

1. Удаляем любые версии MinGW, которые у вас уже стоят. Поставим новую из MSYS2.
2. Качаем и устанавливаем MSYS2 отсюда: https://www.msys2.org/
3. Запускаем его экзешником `mingw64.exe`, это важно. Если запустили правильно, в терминале будет написано `MINGW64` (не `MSYS`) розовыми буквами.
4. Обновляемся командой `pacman -Syuu`. Если в процессе обновления консоль закроется, ее нужно перезапустить и ввести ту же команду, чтобы завершить обновление.
5. Ставим компилятор и дебаггер, и еще кое-что: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`.
6. Ставим постгрес: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql`

Собираем из этой же консоли, командой `g++`.

Comment: а после q++ что делать?

Comment: $ g++
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Вот какая ошибка

Comment: как мне в этом терминале установить libpq-dev ?

Comment: @Anna (6) команда в ответе его ставит. *"после q++ что делать?"* С помощью `g++` компилировать программу. Если не умеете из консоли, то компилируйте не из консоли. Вы же как-то до этого MinGW пользовались, так это такой же MinGW.

Comment: Я не пользовалась MinGW

Comment: @Anna Вы под соседним ответом написали, что уже успели поставить его. Раз не пользовались - то гуглите. Объяснять в комментах долго.

Comment: как мне в MSYS2 ввести команду установки пакета libpq-dev??? меня это сейчас интересует

Comment: @Anna Я же сказал, (6) команда поставила все, что вам нужно. На MSYS2 пакет с постгресом называется не так, а `mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql`.

Comment: у меня все равно в vscode не видит нужный заголовок

Comment: @Anna Это проблемы vscode. Гуглите, или запостите отдельный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), может кто-то подскажет.